# WSO2 and sharepoint SSO setup

Tags: sharepoint, wso2, wso2-identity-server

The case: A client asked for SSO to access their internal SharePoint applications externally (They will add Exchange later on), they do not care if the device is on the domain and they want the experience to be seamless, so anyone with a valid user name and password regardless of whatever device they are using can access the apps.

I have followed the tutorial on WSO2 website to use WSO2 Identity Server 5.3 (passive STS) as an identity provider for SharePoint 2016, and after some tinkering it worked.

https://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/05/tutorial-sso-for-microsoft-sharepoint-web-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/

Then I added another application in sharepoint, added it as a second service provider in WSO2 Identity serverand, added the second realm to the sharepoint trusted provider.

Now the 2 applications only work if I start a new session in my browser or clear cookies, after looking into it, when I open the second application in a different tab it is taking the URI of the first application I opened rather than the its own, and it fails as the realm setup in the second service provider does not match the realm for the application in SharePoint.

So here are my questions:

1- Am I doing the SSO using WSO2 incorrectly (Thus the tutorial title is misleading) , and is the passive STS federation , simply that, a federation and not the way to do the SSO in WSO2 Identity Server? If not, could you please tell me what exactly I need to do to fix my issue?

2- If the above is the wrong approach is using SAML Web SSO configuration the right answer? If so, what is the realm that I should use for the sharepoint applications, and is passive STS needed at all in this case?